# How to get SwiftUI view to update when properties of an object contained within a list of objects change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view which is accessing a dictionary of objects.  If the dictionary itself changes, the view updates.  So in my example, I have a dictionary of objects, and the view shows the list of objects with their details.  If I add (or remove) an object, the list updates properly.  So all this is good.

But if one of the object instances change - so I modify properties of one of the objects in the dictionary - the changes are not detected and propagated to the SwiftUI views.

I thought that making the object observable and marking the properties as @Published would help, but it doesn’t.

Here's the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var mediaModel = MediaModel()
    
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            List {
        ForEach(Array(mediaModel.mediaDictionary.keys), id: \.self) { key in
            if let mediaInfo = mediaModel.mediaDictionary[key] {
            MediaInfoView(mediaInfo: mediaInfo)
            }
        }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Media List")
        .onAppear {
        // Add some initial data to the dictionary for testing
        for _ in 1...5 {
            mediaModel.generate()
        }
        }
    }
    HStack {
        Button {
        mediaModel.generate()
        } label: {
        Text("Add")
        }
        Button {
        mediaModel.modify() 
        } label: {
        Text("Modify")
        }
    }
    }
}
```

and here's the model

```
class MediaInfo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var size: Int
    @Published var bitrate: Int
    
    init(name: String, size: Int, bitrate: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.bitrate = bitrate
    }
}

class MediaModel: ObservableObject {
    var next : Int = 0
    @Published var mediaDictionary: [Int: MediaInfo] = [:]
    
    let names : [String] = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ]
    
    public func add(name: String, size: Int, bitrate: Int) {
        mediaDictionary[next] = MediaInfo(name: name, size: size, bitrate: bitrate)
        next += 1
    }
    public func generate() {
        mediaDictionary[next] = MediaInfo(name: names[Int.random(in: 0..<names.count)], size: Int.random(in: 0..<100), bitrate: Int.random(in: 0..<100))
        next += 1
    }

    
    // TODO: This should update what is shown in the view
    public func modify() {
        for (_, info) in mediaDictionary {
            info.bitrate = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            info.size = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            // Tried adding the following but it didn't help    
            info.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I get the view to update as expected?

Comment: Every ObservableObject has the wrapped with an “Object wrapper”